# how pass from to another Layout using View.OnClickListener and dynamic buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello, I create buttons dynamic and now I want when one of this buttons click, pass to another layout, but I can't! maybe somebody can give me solution, thank you

onCreate:

```
enter code here//-------------------Creating Buttons as per in server -------------------------------
        final Button[] myButton = new Button[jsonArray.length()];
        int count = jsonArray.length();
       for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) { //upside down -> HAFUH
       // for (int i = jsonArray.length(); i > 0 ; i--) {
            final Button rowButton = new Button(this);// create a new button

            --count;//to upside down the buttons, that mean: check last will be on Top

         //   rowButton.setText(dateIn[count] + "  KM: "+ kmIn[count]+" GAS: "+ gasIn[count]);
           rowButton.setText( "KM: "+ kmIn[count]+" GAS: "+ gasIn[count]+"    "+dateIn[count]);
           rowButton.setId(Integer.parseInt(idIn[count]));//string convert to int "ID"
           /*-----------Build onClick and what happened after ------------*/
            rowButton.setOnClickListener(btnClick(myButton[i]));//WHEN Click on button
           /*-------------FINISH Build onClick and what happened after---*/
           b.addView(rowButton);
           // save a reference to the button for later
           myButton[i] = rowButton;

        }//end for jsonArray
        /************Finish Creating Buttons as per in server**********************************/
    }//END IF FOR JSON AND BUILD BUTTON
}//End Create Button
```

outside onCreate method, in the class:

```
enter code hereprivate View.OnClickListener btnClick(final Button button) {
    return new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,GalleryHistoryCheckIn.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
}
```

I expect just pass to another class

Answer (score 0):

HAHA I understand what was my problem, this is answer
method onCreate:
     final Button[] myButton = new Button[jsonArray.length()];

```
        int count = jsonArray.length();
       for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) { //upside down -> HAFUH
       // for (int i = jsonArray.length(); i > 0 ; i--) {
            final Button rowButton = new Button(this);// create a new button

            --count;//to upside down the buttons, that mean: check last will be on Top

         //   rowButton.setText(dateIn[count] + "  KM: "+ kmIn[count]+" GAS: "+ gasIn[count]);
           rowButton.setText( "KM: "+ kmIn[count]+" GAS: "+ gasIn[count]+"    "+dateIn[count]);
           rowButton.setId(Integer.parseInt(idIn[count]));//string convert to int "ID"
           /*-----------Build onClick and what happened after ------------*/
           // rowButton.setOnClickListener(btnClick(myButton[i]));//WHEN Click on button
           /*-------------FINISH Build onClick and what happened after---*/
           b.addView(rowButton);
           // save a reference to the button for later
           myButton[i] = rowButton;
            myButton[i].setOnClickListener(btnClick(rowButton));
       }//end for jsonArray
        /************Finish Creating Buttons as per in server**********************************/
    }//END IF FOR JSON AND BUILD BUTTON
}//End Create Button
```

outside of on create but in class:

```
  private View.OnClickListener btnClick(final Button button) {
    return new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),GalleryHistoryCheckIn.class);
            intent.putExtra("result", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
}
```